# How to make one physical disk as one device and mount to OS

Tags: linux

I'm newbie to Linux and I met issues below.

I have two nodes and each one has 7 HDD plugged, let's name them as A and B.

When I list disk with `lsblk` on A, it shows like below:

```
sdb       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk /mnt/DP_disk1
sdc       8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk /mnt/DP_disk2
sdd       8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk /mnt/DP_disk3
sde       8:64   0 931.5G  0 disk /mnt/DP_disk4
sdf       8:80   0 931.5G  0 disk /mnt/DP_disk5
sdg       8:96   0 931.5G  0 disk /mnt/DP_disk6
sdh       8:112  0 931.5G  0 disk /mnt/DP_disk7
```

When I list disk on B, it show like below:

```
sdb           8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:17   0     1G  0 part
├─sdb2        8:18   0     8G  0 part
└─sdb3        8:19   0 438.1G  0 part
sdc           8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1        8:33   0 931.5G  0 part
sdd           8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdd1        8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
```

I want to make B also one physical disk as one device and named also from sdb to sdbh. To be simple straight, when I input `lsblk` on B, it has exactly the same output of A. What can I do?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm told that it has 7 HDD and the `size` is also a hint.

Comment: You need to delete the partitions that are on the disks on B.  Be aware that you'll loose any data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A has 7 HDDs, each one 931.5 GiB in size. They aren't partitioned, but formatted directly (aka *superfloppy*).

B has only three HDDs. First one, `sdb` (total capacity 447.1 GiB), has three partitions (1 GiB + 8 GiB + 438.1 GiB). Other two, `sdc` and `sdd`, are 931.5 GiB each and are unpartitioned.

If you want to have partitions gone, format those disks using this or similar command:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
```

And reload kernel partition info:

```
partprobe
```

**This will erase your partitions.**

Comment: Thanks, this information helps.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state why you need exactly the whole disk. If you want to spread a capable filesystem or software RAID across several disks, you can do that with partitions, too: Delete existing partitions and create one new partition of maximum size.

As you are a newbie, consider if you are ready to handle such commands, specifically on systems with important data. One wrong command on that level can kick a complete filesystem/database off the table. And you might even notice that much later.

Having only disks (and replacement disks) with the exact same size is highly recommended for RAID 1+, otherwise you may get into trouble. Or allocate a safe minimum size.

Comment: Thanks for this value add answer. I use entire disk for ceph related deployment. My issues have been fixed with the help from gronostaj. I will give you a upvote for extra information you provided, thanks.